# Locate Database File in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

I have created a file named "MyFile.db" using SQLite3 from my C#.net application. This file got created in my "D:\MyProject\bin" folder. I have created a table named "MyTable" inside "MyFile.db" from same C# app.

Now I am running sqlite3.exe from my "C:\" drive to get Command Line Shell For SQLite.

How can I get the file "D:\MyProject\bin\MyFile.db"  in the SQLite Command Line Shell 
i.e, how can I locate the file "MyFile.db" in the command shell to get the data from "MyTable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start sqlite3.exe with the database as a paramater:

```
sqlite3.exe D:\MyProject\bin\MyFile.db
```

Or you could open sqlite3 as you are and attach the database at runtime using the syntax described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)